# JSON Parsing creating error

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse Rotten Tomatoes JSON API to my App. This is the layout:

```
<!-- ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/poster" />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Rightend Arrow -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
<!-- City -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/namelisttext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:text="Movie Name"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />
<!-- Weather Information -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rtscore"
    android:layout_width="18dip"
    android:layout_height="18dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/namelisttext"
    android:layout_below="@id/namelisttext"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/rtscore" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rtscoretext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rtscore"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/rtscore"
    android:text="Score"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/audscore"
    android:layout_width="18dip"
    android:layout_height="18dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/namelisttext"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rtscoretext"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/audscore" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/audscoretext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/audscore"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/audscore"
    android:text="Score"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/castlisttext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/namelisttext"
    android:layout_below="@id/rtscore"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/releaseyearlisttext"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Casts"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/releaseyearlisttext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rtscore"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:text="Year"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

In the textviews named rtscoretext and audscore text, I am trying to get this JSONData named critics_score and audience_score from this link http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Movies_Search. Here is the code for that.,

```
ma = new MyAdapter();

private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        // make a request to the specified url
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                // make a HTTP request
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    // request successful - read the response and close the
                    // connection
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                } else {
                    // request failed - close the connection
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Test", "Couldn't make a successful request!");
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        // if the request above completed successfully, this method will
        // automatically run so you can do something with the response
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);

            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    // convert the String response to a JSON object,
                    // because JSON is the response format Rotten Tomatoes uses
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                    // fetch the array of movies in the response
                    JSONArray movies = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("movies");

                    // add each movie's title to an array
                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                        movieTitles.add(movie.getString("title"));
                    }

                    movieID = new String[movies.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject id = movies.getJSONObject(i);
                        movieID[i] = id.getString("id");
                    }


                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject ratingsobj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("ratings");
                            String criticsrating = ratingsobj.get("critics_score").toString();
                            rtscore.add(criticsrating);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            rtscore.add("Unavailable");
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject ratingsobj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("ratings");
                            String audrating = ratingsobj.get("audience_score").toString();
                            audscore.add(audrating);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            audscore.add("Unavailable");
                        }
                    }


                    // update the UI
                    refreshMoviesName();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("Test", "Failed to parse the JSON response!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void refreshMoviesName() {
        moviesList.setAdapter(ma);
        ma.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return movieTitles.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return movieTitles.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent, false);
            TextView nametext = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.namelisttext);
            TextView casttext = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.castlisttext);
            TextView yeartext = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.releaseyearlisttext);
            TextView rtscoretext = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.rtscoretext);
            TextView audscoretext = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.audscoretext);

            nametext.setText(movieTitles.get(position));
            casttext.setText(castnames.get(position));
            yeartext.setText(releaseyear.get(position));
            rtscoretext.setText(rtscore.get(position));
            audscoretext.setText(audscore.get(position));

            return rl;
        }

    }
```

But the problem is that each and everytime it is setting Unavailable, even if the data is present. In debug mode, I see that it goes to Catch block as soon as it hits the line,

```
JSONObject ratingsobj = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("ratings");
```

I am unable to solve this, someone please help. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Which time?  it hits similar code twice.  My hunch is the second time because you should be combining those two requests

Comment: if it hits the catch block, it means an Exception is being thrown. Why not try logging those exceptions to work out what the problem is, rather than just moving on and forgetting about them

Comment: A `JSONException` will get thrown if you attempt to parse a tag that is not present. Are you sure your `jsonResponse` contains an object with the tag "ratings"?

Comment: Yes, see the link for JSON data.. http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/Movies_Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonResponse` actually doesn't hold the "ratings" object. It is inside each object in the "movies" array. You need something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<movies.length(); i++) {
    try {
        JSONObject movie = movies.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject ratingsobj = movie.getJSONObject("ratings");
        String audrating = ratingsobj.get("audience_score").toString();
        audscore.add(audrating);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        audscore.add("Unavailable");
    }
}
```

I would also really encourage you to go back and consolidate all of the loops through `movies` into a single `for` loop. This will greatly improve the performance of your code.

Comment: 04-23 02:35:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(15271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 02:35:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(15271): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-23 02:35:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(15271):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251) ************************************

Line is 04-23 02:35:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(15271):  at akshat.jaiswal.rottenreviews.SearchActivity$MyAdapter.getView(SearchActivity.java:384)
In base Adapters getview method..

Comment: Which line is that in your code? One of your ArrayLists is empty it would seem.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. And yes it worked., Thank you so extreme much. Really helpful.. Thanx a lott..

Comment: You are very welcome, and I'm glad you got it to work.

Answer (score -1):

Try opt instead of get and see if it works:

```
JSONObject ratingsobj = jsonResponse.optJSONObject("ratings");
```

Comment: This will cause a `NullPointerException` on the very next line if "ratings" is not found. You may want to address that in your answer for clarity.

Comment: Actually that is nested object. Can you please see the link and help me out.?